# How do I get EventSource.onmessage to work?

Tags: java, spring, web, server-sent-events

How do I get EventSource.onmessage to work?

Here is my subscribe and pushevent code:

```
    public SseEmitter subscribe() throws Exception {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(1800000L);

        emitters.add(emitter);

        emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
            synchronized (emitters) {
                emitters.remove(emitter);
            }
        });
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
            emitter.complete();
            emitters.remove(emitter);
        });

        return emitter;
    }
```

```
    @Async
    public void pushEventMap(Map<String, Object> pushMap) throws IOException {
        List<SseEmitter> deadEmitters = new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<String,Object> map = (HashMap<String,Object>) pushMap;

        emitters.forEach(emitter -> {
            try {
                emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("myEvent").data(map));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
                logger_error.error("pushEvent Exception:" + e);
                deadEmitters.add(emitter);
            }
        });
        emitters.removeAll(deadEmitters);
    }
```

The controller for the above service is:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe", produces = "text/event-stream")
    public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> subscribe() throws Exception {

        final SseEmitter emitter = eventService.subscribe();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(emitter, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void publish() throws IOException {
        eventService.pushEventMap(pushMap);
    }
```

I want the client to receive the data of event push through js.

```
const eventInit = () => {

    console.log("eventInit called");
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/itf/subscribe';
    const eventSource = new EventSource(url);

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('===');
        console.log(data);

    }
    eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log('sse open');
        console.log(event);
    }

    eventSource.onerror = (event) => {
        if (event.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            console.log('sse close');
        } else {
            console.log("onerror", e);
        }
    }

}
```

In this state, if I send event-generating data through postman, `sse open` appears on the console.

However, the result of the event is not displayed.

If I directly access `/itf/subscribe` through the url, the result of the event is displayed on the screen. However, I am not receiving the result of the event through `event.onmessage`.

What I want is to raise an event, and then receive the result of the event through the onmessage function.

I am wondering how can I get the result of the event.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with code, the actual issue is when I am writing response to client my response message should look like as below.

```
PrintWriter out = response.write("data: message"+value+"\n\n");
out.flush(); //don't forget to flush
```

In my code I was missing the last part "\n\n" in response object so source.onmessage(datalist) in javascript didn't get hit.

Comment: Is this related to this question, though? I don't see a `response.write()` line in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    eventSource.addEventListener('myEvent', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('addEventListener');
        console.log(data);
        // console.log(data.siteCode);
        eventEffect(data);
    }, false);
```

this is normally work!

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? It looks more like additional information that you should edit the question and add there?

Comment: Am I should answer code in question? @Darren Cook